# Display an element with specific attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="book.xslt"?>
<bookstore>

<book> 
<title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
<title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
<price>20.30</price>
</book>

<book>
<title lang="fr">Exploitation Linux</title>
<price>40.00</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Book Title</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="title[@lang='eng']/text()"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="price/text()"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to display the details only for the title which have attribute `lang="eng"` but i'm getting an unnecessary row where there's no book title but there's the price. Here's the output.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: For future reference, it's far more useful in XSLT questions if you can show your current and/or required outputs as the actual HTML/XML source rather than a picture of how one particular browser renders it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the elements you're processing with the `for-each` to those that have a title in the appropriate language:

```
<xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book[title/@lang = 'eng']">
```

As an aside, you almost never need to use `text()` in an XPath expression, unless you really do want to handle individual text nodes separately.  In situations like yours, where what you care about is the text content of the whole element, just take the `value-of` the element itself:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
```